Through/into in given context
We're halfway through the month.
We're halfway into the month.
To me, both sentences seem fine. But I failed to find more than a single example of into being used in this manner in published works on this site: https://app.ludwig.guru/s/halfway+into+the+month.
Is there any chance the second sentence isn't fine? Also, is there any difference in what these sentences mean?

Halfway into the month sounds odd to me, but this Ngram shows that it began to creep into use in the early 1970s.

"To me, both sentences seem fine." —Sure; both are perfectly valid grammatically and don't misuse either word. But "idiomatic usage" means that sometimes some phrases are said more than others, perhaps for no particular reason.
Comparing "halfway through the month" vs "halfway into the month" shows that "into" is not unheard of, but "through" is much more common. Substituting "movie" for "month" shows a fairly recent rise in popularity for "halfway into the movie," though "through" is still more common there.
